# Beneficial dimension for 2nd order modelling in SGD optimization?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, convergence, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

There are currently mostly used first order methods in SGD optimizers, second order are [often seen too costly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394083/why-second-order-sgd-convergence-methods-are-unpopular-for-deep-learning) as e.g. full Hessian has size $D^2$ in dimension $D$.

But we don't need full Hessian - there is already valuable information in second order model for a low dimensional subspace. For example just maintaining parabola model in a single direction: e.g. from momentum or ADAM method, might improve its choice of step size, and such online parabola model can be cheaply maintained e.g. by just [updating 4 averages](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07063) $(\theta, g,\theta g, \theta^2)$. Is there a successful parabola-enhanced line search?

[image]

Using second order model in $d\leq D$ dimensional subspace, the additional step cost generally grows like $\approx d^2$, allowing to simultaneously optimize in all these directions. However, it is said that neural network landscape is usually flat in most of directions - we need to chose somehow the locally more interesting directions.

Some basic questions here:

- For what dimensional subspace it seems the most beneficial to use 2nd order model? For example: **full Hessian**, or **layer-wise** like in [K-FAC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05671.pdf), or e.g. **a few dimensions** like in [saddle-free Newton](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2572), or in just **a single direction** enhancing first order method, or maybe **none**? If in a few, are there some hints how to choose this dimension?
- How to optimally choose such locally promising $d$-dimensional subspace - where second order model seems the most beneficial? [Krylov subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace) like in saddle-free Newton, or maybe better some [online-PCA](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/opca.pdf) of recent gradients, or something different?
- Is local dependence important - is it sufficient to sometimes stop and estimate Hessian, or maybe it is better to go toward online methods: frequently updating the model?